# String indicies must be integers in Python

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to get url value from the api, but have an issue saying **TypeError: string indices must be integers**

Here is the array that I get from api:

```js
[
{
"created_utc": 1643524062,
"title": "title",
"url": "https://i.redd.it/tmd5shz9rre81.gif",
},
{
"created_utc": 1643530657,
"title": "title",
"url": "https://i.redd.it/qqjykysxase81.gif",
}
]
```

And here is the code I use to get the url:

```js
url = "https://reddit-meme.p.rapidapi.com/memes/trending"

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "83df5aba87msh4580fa40781b33cp12157bjsnb4b412cb57da",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "reddit-meme.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text[0]["url"])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `response.text` give you *text*. You want `response.json()`.

Comment: you printed `text` which returns a string. use `json.loads()` to convert that string to a python list

Answer (score 0):

`response.text` is a string, you have to parse it first, with the json librarie, like this:

```py
import requests
import json


url = "https://reddit-meme.p.rapidapi.com/memes/trending"

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "83df5aba87msh4580fa40781b33cp12157bjsnb4b412cb57da",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "reddit-meme.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)

print(data[0]["url"])
```